# Search and subsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I can implement a simple text search and looked thru several guides but I cannot seem to get my head wrapped around this: How do I search for a main object and then do a sub-search for objects that `belong_to` that main one?

I'm not even sure I can explain it properly, so here's a small illustration I made:

http://i1343.photobucket.com/albums/o788/534221/search-subsearch-add2_zpsbdaa61e2.png

Any help is immensely appreciated, be it guides, tutorials, straight up code or anything really.

Comment: Do you want to do the sub-search after you found the main object?  In that case for your sub-search, add a hidden_field and set it to the value of the id of the main object on the page. In your query, include the object_id to restrict the query to that object.  If this is what you want I can post some code.

Comment: Yes, but basically I'm not trying to find the main object (Hammer in the example) but rather its associated objects - the different kinds of hammers from different manufacturers.

Comment: so do you have a tool_id field for each item?

Comment: Yes, tool_id:integer. I wrote that above scaffold by hand and forgot it from the sketch. Another way to achieve this would probably be to include all the Manufacturers in the Tool object but I need to add them as they come along so I can't predetermine a set amount of Manufacturers. Is it even possible to create the Tool object so I can create another object straight inside of it? Or do we proceed a above, with `belongs_to`?